# Display inline images with specific image style

Tags: media

Is there some way to get inline images (inserted with Media/FCKEditor) to be displayed in a specific image style? I can only get them displayed in the original format.

I have tried the Picture module but that somehow "uses" the class attribute so I can not set a specific class for an image.

Thanks!